# Codeigniter: Getting the name of the textbox from view to get it in the model

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I just want to ask on how can I get the value of a textbox name in my view to put it in my model.

Here is my view:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<form action="save_new_inventorytype" method="POST" id="frm_newinventorytype" name="frm_newinventorytype">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add New Inventory Type</legend>
        <label id="lbl_tablename" name="lbl_tablename">Inventory Type Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txt_tablename" name="additional1[txt_tablename]" size="30" /><br>
        <label id="lbl_columns" name="lbl_columns" style="position: absolute; top: 276px;">Column Name:</label>
        <label style="position: absolute; top: 276px; left: 396px;">Type:</label>
        <label style="position: absolute; top: 276px; left: 610px;">Length/Values:</label><br>
        <br>
        <div id="TextBoxesGroup">
            <div id="textboxdiv1">
                <input type="text" id="txt_columnname1" name="additional[txt_columnname1]" size="30"/>&nbsp;
                <select id="cbo_columntype1" name="additional[cbo_columntype1]" style="width: 200px;">
                    <option>INT</option>
                    <option>VARCHAR</option>
                    <option>TEXT</option>
                    <option>DATE</option>
                 </select>&nbsp;
                 <input type="text" id="txt_columnlength1" name="additional[txt_columnlength1]" size="30"/><br><br>
             </div>
        </div>

        <button type="button" style="position: absolute; top: 295px; right: 495px;"  class="btn_plusvalue btn-success btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
        <!--<button type="button" style="position: absolute; top: 295px; right: 415px;" class="btn_removevalue btn-danger btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button><br>-->
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn_addtable btn-success btn-sm" id="btn_addtable" name="btn_addtable">Save Inventory Type</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn_canceltable btn-danger btn-sm" id="btn_canceltable" name="btn_canceltable">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn_cleartable btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn_cleartable" name="btn_cleartable" onclick="reset();">Clear</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot in case you're confused:

[image]

every time I click the plus button another set of textbox and selectbox is loaded with different name and here is my jquery on that:

```
$('.btn_plusvalue').click(function(){
    var counter = 2;
    if(counter > 15){
        alert("Only 15 columns allowed!");
        return false;
    }
//        
//                 = $(document.createElement('div'))
//                                      .attr("id", "textboxdiv");

    var newTextBoxDiv = $('<input type="text" size="30" name="additional[txt_columnname' + counter +  ']" id="txt_columnname' + counter + '" value="" />&nbsp;\n\
                           <select style="width: 200px;" name="additional[cbo_columntype' + counter + ']" id="cbo_columntype' + counter + '">\n\
                                 <option>INT</option>\n\
                                 <option>VARCHAR</option>\n\
                                 <option>TEXT</option>\n\
                                 <option>DATE</option>\n\
                            </select>&nbsp;\n\
                            <input type="text" size="30" name="additional[txt_columnlength' + counter + ']" id="txt_columnlength' + counter + '"/><br><br>');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#textboxdiv1");

    counter++;
});
```

My problem now is in my model, how can I get the name of the added set of textbox and selectbox, here is a code in my model:

```
public function maintenance_add_inventorytype($add){

    $fields = array(
                   'ID' => array('type' => 'INT',
                                'constraint' => '50',
                                'auto_increment' => TRUE,
                                'PRIMARY' => TRUE),

                    $add['txt_columnname1'] => array('type' => $add['cbo_columntype1'],
                                                          'constraint' => $add['txt_columnlength1']),
                    ); 
     $this->dbforge->add_field($fields);
     $this->dbforge->add_key('ID', TRUE);
     $this->dbforge->create_table($add['txt_tablename']);

 }
```

and here is the code in my controller:

```
public function save_new_inventorytype(){
    $additional_inventory = array($_POST['additional1'],
                                  $_POST['additional']);

    $this->inventory_model->maintenance_add_inventorytype($additional_inventory);
    redirect('inventorysys_controller/maintenance');
}
```

I've managed to get the value of the first set of textboxes and selectbox. The problem is I don't know how to get the name of the added set of textboxes in order for me to get the value that I input on the added set of the textboxes..

Need your help so bad. Man I'm getting crazy because of this. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is way to much to do here for me to code it all for you but here are some pointers to help you make this process much easier for yourself.

First, you dont have to create your own indexes to manage the multiple rows the user can generate. Use this syntax on your `name=""` names.

```
<input type="text" name="col_name[]" size="30"/>
<select name="col_type[]" style="width: 200px;">
<input type="text" name="col_len[]" size="30"/>
```

This will return you, in the $_POST array 3 fields each of which will be an array called `col_name`, `col_type` and `col_len`. So

```
col_name[0] and col_type[0] and col_len[0] is the first row
col_name[1] and col_type[1] and col_len[1] is the second row etc

count($_POST['col_name]); // tells you how many row were entered
```

And you can process the entered data easily with a `foreach()` statement.

```
foreach ( $_POST['col_name'] as $idx => $name ) {
    $type = $_POST['col_type'][$idx];
    $len  = $_POST['col_len'][$idx];
    // do whatever you want with $name,$type,$len
}
```

Now you dont need to bother with all the index management code, at least some of which I believe you had wrongly coded.

Now I would be tempted to place this table of rows in an actual `<table>` this will allow you to simplify your `$('.btn_plusvalue').click(function(){` processing as JQuery has a nice syntax to allow you to identify the LAST row in a table and then `clone` that row and then append it to the end of the tables `<tbody>`.

See [jQuery :last Selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

See [jQuery .clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)

See [jQuery .append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

You can then just clone the last row of the table and remove the data from the 2 fields the user entered data into,  and you get the dropdown pre-filled for free. *A much simpler process*

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are using name of the text box as

```
additional[txt_columnname' + counter +  ']"
```

Controller:

```
public function save_new_inventorytype(){
   $additional_inventory[] = array();
    if(isset($_POST)){
        for($i=0; $i<15 ; $i++)
        {
         $additional_inventory['tablename'][$i] = 'table_name';
         $additional_inventory['name'][$i] = $_POST['additional[txt_columnname'.$i.']'];
         $additional_inventory['type'][$i] = $_POST['additional[cbo_columntype'.$i.']'];
         $additional_inventory['length'][$i] = $_POST['additional[txt_columnlength'.$i.']'];
        }
    }

    $this->inventory_model->maintenance_add_inventorytype($additional_inventory);
    redirect('inventorysys_controller/maintenance');
}
```

Model:

```
    public function maintenance_add_inventorytype($add){

    if(isset($add)){
        for($i=0; $i<count($add); $i++)
        {
$fields = array(
         $add[name][$i] => array('type' => $add['type'][$i],'constraint' => $add['length'][$i])); 
        }
     $primary = array(
                   'ID' => array('type' => 'INT',
                                'constraint' => '50',
                                'auto_increment' => TRUE,
                                'PRIMARY' => TRUE));
     array_push($fields,$primary);
     $this->dbforge->add_field($fields);
     $this->dbforge->add_key('ID', TRUE);
     $this->dbforge->create_table('tablename');
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can I write that code on the model? I'm getting all the value of the texboxes and the added textboxes in my controller when I var_dump() it. My only problem is in the model.

Comment: No, You will not get post values in model.
You need to get all values from POST in controller and save them in array. Pass that array to model. But, you can not retrieve values from POST in model.

Comment: Actually I'm getting all the values from my $_POST in my controller, on my code above. My problem really is how can I put those values in the model.

Comment: I have made changes in my code. If i helped u little then please vote to answer. :)

Comment: I'm so sorry but the code you made didn't work. It didn't get any value on my view.